# JQuery doesn't apply css rule to table on IE 6 and 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a form with 2 radio buttons and when a user clicks on one of the radio buttons a select input appears.
It works on Chrome, FF and IE 8+ but it doesn't work with IE 6 and 7.

Here is what I've done :

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="Equipier" value="oui" id="oui">Oui
<input type="radio" name="Equipier" value="non" id="non">Non

<select name="choixequipier" id="selectequipier">
    <option value="non">-</option>
    <option value="matin">Matin</option>
    <option value="apres midi">Arpès-midi</option>
    <option value="nuit">Nuit</option>
    <option value="week end">Week-end</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=Equipier]:radio").change(function () {
        if ($("#oui").attr("checked")) {
            $('#equipierchoix').css("display", "table-row");
        }
        else {
            $('#equipierchoix').css("display", "none");
            $('#selectequipier option[value="non"]').attr("selected", "selected");
        }
    })
});
```

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1

How can I solve the problem for IE 6 and 7 ?

**EDIT**

I'm able to enter in the `if` statement so it's a problem with this line :

```
$('#equipierchoix').css("display", "table-row");
```

Comment: In the edit, are you sure about that condition in the `if` statement?

Comment: Also, please try to describe in better detail how it doesn't work in IE6 or 7. What happens when you click the radio button? What should happen? You should also update the question title, right now it's a bit generic and totally misleading.

Comment: i can't find an element with ID `oui` nor an element with ID `equipierchoix` in your HTML

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes because it works on Chrome but not in FF or IE. When I click on radio `oui` the select is displayed, but when I click with IE nothing is done and no error

Comment: In the edit, read that `if` condition again. you *do* know the difference between assignment and comparison for equality? And no, it's *definitely* not the same problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg oh yes, `=`instead of `==` thanks. I've deleted my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Internet Explorer has this thing called conditional tags in older versions

This is all IE code of IE 8 and above

```
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|!(IE)]><!-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=Equipier]:radio").change(function () {
        if ($("#oui").attr("checked")) {
            $('#equipierchoix').css("display", "table-row");
        }
        else {
            $('#equipierchoix').css("display", "none");
            $('#selectequipier option[value="non"]').attr("selected", "selected");
        }
    })
});
</script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Here you put any work arounds for anything obsolete and lesser than IE 8(lt = lesser than)

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name=Equipier]:radio").change(function () {
        if ($("#oui").attr("checked")) {
            $('#equipierchoix').css("display", "block");
        }
        else {
            $('#equipierchoix').css("display", "none");
            $('#selectequipier option[value="non"]').attr("selected", "selected");
        }
    })
});
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

I think that `display:block` should work, but I don't have a proper version of IE at hand to test.

And otherwise you can play with `$('#equipierchoix').css("visibility", "hidden");` and  `$('#equipierchoix').css("visibility", "visible");` if the `display:block` fails for IE 6 & 7 code

**EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION**

You need to put **both** blocks on the page.
In the first block you place all the code that should only run for "recent" browsers

in the second block you place all the code that is going to have to work or adapted for functionality for ie6-7

code that works for anything doesn't have to be encased by the conditional comments.

Comment: It's look like the solution but it doesn't work on Chrome or FF, is it the right comparaison for all browser ?

Comment: In the first block you put all the code for everything "normal". In the second block you put all the code for the obsolete IE browsers. You need to use both blocks in your page. Put all css styling fixes in the IE 6 & 7 part. a quick example: http://jsfiddle.net/57fhsynb/

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer supports [`display: table-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) only since version 8.0.

Solve the problem by dropping support for dead browsers, or by using an actual table.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain "checked", you should use 'prop' not 'attr':

```
$("#oui").prop("checked")
```

Also '#equipierchoix' doesn't seem to be the right ID, it would appear to be:

```
$('#selectequipier').css("display", "none");
```

Check caniuse.com to check what else is valid for those very old browsers, although I see that that site is starting to phase them out.

A sample plunk is here:

[Plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/OX1lLv/)